# How to reset/uncheck radio button onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 2 radio button with 2 group.

The structure is like this

1. Main Radio 1
2. Main Radio 2

Under Main Radio 2, there's two more sub radio button.

1. Main Radio 1
2. Main Radio 2

   - Sub Radio 1
   - Sub Radio 2

What am I doing is, in default stage, it will only show Main Radio 1 and Main Radio 2 button. When choose Main Radio 2, two sub radio button of Main Radio 2 appear.

When choose back to Main Radio 1, it will hide the list of Main Radio 2.

The one that I want to achieve is,

When click Main Radio 1, the selection that I made for Sub Radio 1 or Sub Radio 2, want to be uncheck / reset too.

I tried with this javascript, but no success.

```
document.getElementById("subradiobuttons").reset();
```

Please kindly help me the solutions. Thank you.

With Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best approach for a simple task like this does not needs a full JavaScript library like jQuery.

```js
document.getElementById("main2").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    document.getElementById("subCheckButtons").style.opacity = 1;
}, false);
document.getElementById("main1").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    document.getElementById("subCheckButtons").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("sub1").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("sub2").checked = false;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="main1" name="main" />
<input type="radio" id="main2" name="main" />
<div id="subCheckButtons" style="opacity:0;">
    <input type="radio" id="sub1" name="sub" class="subCheck" />
    <input type="radio" id="sub2" name="sub" class="subCheck" />
</div>
```

Or see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRFdk/1/).

Comment: I tried your one, but when I choose back to Main Radio 1, and select Main Radio 2, my selection is already there. What I want to do is reset / uncheck totally.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to integrate with my code. Will let you know the result.

Comment: No problem, if this was useful to you remember to mark it as the right answer :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that will reset all inputs to their default position if someone clicks on "Main Radio 1."

```js
//Clear all inputs.
function clearInputs(form) {
    "use strict";

    //Gather all inputs within selected form.
    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input");

    //Clear the inputs.
    inputs.forEach(function (input) {
        if (input.hasAttribute("checked") === true) {
            input.checked = true;
        } else {
            input.checked = false;
        }
    });
}

//Monitor "Main Radio 1" for clicks.
function monitorMainRadio1() {
    "use strict";

    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    const mainRadio1 = document.getElementById("main-radio1");

    mainRadio1.addEventListener("click", function () {
        clearInputs(form);
    });
}

//Invoke the monitorMainRadio1 function.
monitorMainRadio1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this but...

`<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById("subradiobuttons").Checked = false;" />`

Or you could call a Javascript function to do a bit more work/logic

[This page has what you need](http://www.somacon.com/p143.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is much, much quicker to do this with jQuery than JavaScript. I recommend you do something like this;

Give the radio boxes something like this

```
<input type="radio" name="main1">
<input type="radio" name="main2">
    <input type="radio" name="sub">
    <input type="radio" name="sub">​
```

Then with jQuery you can do this

```
$('input[name=main1]').on('click', function() {
    $('input[name=sub]').attr('checked', false);
});
```

I've assumed here that you've figured out a way to hide the sub radio buttons. ​

See a fiddle of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xNzGC/2/)

Also, make sure that you include jQuery at the top of the `<script></script>` tags containing this code.

```
script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
```

Comment: It is quicker to write but not faster to process for the browser

Comment: @DavidDiez - jQuery is Javascript. Bad JS code can be as detrimental to performance as bad jQ code. The browser reads it the same way as jQ IS JS.

Comment: Good or regular javascript code HAS better performance than good jQuery code. jQuery does a lot more things for the same tasks due to jQuery is a javascript library that works for a lot more things than just this simple task. IMHO there is not need to use jQuery here...

Comment: @JoshuaM, I tried your example, it works, but I am trying to integrate with my code and no success yet :( . I don't know why. I am still trying and let you know the result.

Comment: IMHO there is no need to use JS. It's an opinion. I think you're just being really facetious, why not use something that is already built for you that makes practically NO difference to performance? It's completely ridiculous. @knightrider, see my edit

Comment: @Joshua M - As you said before, if you are using jQuery your are using JS so.. you are using JS... If the performance is not a priority for you it is not my problem...

Comment: @DavidDiez, Performance is practically the same! It really does not make that much difference. Show me some concrete proof where using jQuery over JavaScript is a huge detriment to page speed.

Comment: @JoshuaM, yes, I already included jquery. I will try to do it again, if I cannot get it, I will provide you my code. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @JoshuaM - The request to load jQuery is a request you save. The time browser spends reading your code and mine is almost the same, but the point is that you are killing flies with cannons...!

Comment: @DavidDiez Also, jQuery works better in IE. And who cares? If I can kill more flies with cannons than rocks, why shouldn't I?

Comment: @JoshuaM - I think an answer like that is all I need to stop discussing this topic

Answer (score 0):

This code will work similar like checkbox

```
$("input[type='radio'].xyz").click(function(){
        if (this.previous) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
        this.previous = this.checked;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Reset the radiobutton or `RadiobuttonList` in the form:

```
private void ResetFormControlValues(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            ResetFormControlValues(c);
        }
        else
        {
            switch ((c.GetType().ToString()))
            {
                case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox":
                    ((TextBox)c).Text = "";
                    break;
                case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox":
                    ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
                    break;
                case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton":
                    ((RadioButton)c).Checked = false;
                    break;
                case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList":
                    ((DropDownList)c).SelectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript, friend!