# Uncheck a radio button after clicking on it again

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to uncheck a radio button after clicking on it again.
For example, when i click for the first time it gets checked, but I want that after clicking on it again, it gets unchecked

I tried the following [How to reset/uncheck radio button onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885551/how-to-reset-uncheck-radio-button-onclick-event)

But it does not work

Can someone help me out? thanks

```
 <input id="button1" type="radio" name="optradio"></input>
```

Comment: So you want it to operate like a checkbox?

Comment: Why not just use a checkbox?

Comment: Yes I would want it to work as a checkbox

Comment: As previous comments, and yourself, have pointed out -- using a checkbox will help you with this behavior.  If you want it to look like a radio button, you could direct your attention into "how to make custom checkboxes" -- a lot of problems creep up in design/development when trying to re-invent an existing tool.  It's always better to use the default tool than try and shoe-horn a solution out of something different.

Comment: Ok thanks. i will use a checkbox then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
      toggle0=1;
      btn0=document.getElementById("button1");
      btn0.addEventListener("click", function(e){

        if(toggle0==0){
            toggle0=1
            btn0.checked=false;
            }else{
                toggle0=0;
            btn0.checked=true;
            }

      });


        }
</script>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it's a lot easier to use a simple checkbox instead of implementing this JS. Depending on the functionality you want.